# How does the one-dimensional "substitution rule" fit into the general transformation formula

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

When considering integrals, we often use substitution in the following sense: Let $\lambda > 0$

$\varphi(y)=x =-\lambda y\implies dx = -\lambda dy$ such that $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{\frac{-a}{\lambda}}^{\frac{-b}{\lambda}}-\lambda f(-\lambda y)dy$

But now the more general transformation formula states that $dx = \lvert \det D\varphi(y)\rvert dy=\lambda dy$

I am confused how the the general transformation formula is a generalization of the substitution formula mentioned in the beginning, because in the substitution formula we do not take the absolute value, while in the general transformation formula we use the absolute value, leading to two different answers:

$$ dx = \lambda dy \; \; dx = - \lambda dy$$

Comment: The bounds of integration will change in the substitution. They will become out of order to account for the $-$ sign.

Comment: @Mason could you explain this more? The bounds also change in the general transformation formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a < b$. We want to compute $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx$. Using the substitution $x = -\lambda y$, $dx = -\lambda dy$ we get
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx = \int_{-a/\lambda}^{-b/\lambda}f(-\lambda y)(-\lambda)\,dy = \int_{-b/\lambda}^{-a/\lambda}f(-\lambda y)\lambda\,dy.$$

For using the general change of variable formula, we write the integral as $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx = \int_{[a, b]}f(x)\,dx$. These are equal by definition, since the left hand side is defined to be the right hand side. In this case we substitute $x = g(y) := -\lambda y$, $dx = |\det(g'(y))|dy =\lambda dy$. Now the set of $y$ that we integrate over is $g^{-1}([a, b]) = [-b/\lambda, -a/\lambda]$. Thus
$$\int_{[a, b]}f(x)\,dx = \int_{[-b/\lambda, -a/\lambda]}f(-\lambda y)\lambda dy = \int_{-b/\lambda}^{-a/\lambda}f(-\lambda y)\lambda\,dy.$$